# SQL Server error

Tags: sql-server

I am getting a fatal error on following code.

> exec [sp_ExternalApp_UPDATEUSER] 'ZZZ', XXXXX','DDDDD','DDDFFDD','EREE', 'EREWWWWW',1,1,'QWEW@DFEE.DER','DEFF','XXXX','DDDD'

Following error occurred:

> Location:   memilb.cpp:1624
>   Expression:  pilb->m_cRef == 0
>   SPID:        79
>   Process ID:  2256
>
> Msg 3624, Level 20, State 1, Procedure sp_ExternalApp_UPDATEUSER, Line 32
>   A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details
>   Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Also, *is* there any further information in the SQL Server error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you

I got the solution. 
I have used UPPER() function. As I removed that function, my problem solved

Comment: I think this has been fixed if you install latest service pack http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259641/sql-server-assertion-in-mmilb-cpp-1624-pilb-m-cref-0-when-using-upper-and-like-inside-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Like the message said, check your error log, there might be more detail in there..what does this proc do does it use *sp_OACreate* or calls *xp_cmdshell*?  Post the proc code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the database for corruption. Try

```
DBCC CHECKDB
```

(before doing so, read the documentation on that command! See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx )